# java rest streaming upload

Tags: java, rest, upload, streaming

Using Rest webservices (WS) to upload file whose size is between 10 and 50 MB
At the moment, we use Java, Jax-RS and CXF for doing it.

The behavior of this stack is to buffer the uploaded file by writing them into a temporary file (because we have large files). This is fine for most users.

Is it possible to stream directly from the socket input?
(not from a whole file in memory nor from a temporary file)

My purpose is to have less overhead on IOs and CPUs (each file is written twice : 1 buffer and 1 final). The WS only have to write the files (sometimes several in the same HTTPrequest) to a path that I calculate from the HTTP query string.

Thanks for your attention